# Confusion over the actual type of a referenced abstract type

Tags: scala, types, type-alias

Below I have a purposefully complicated Hello World applictaion in which I cannot figure out for the life of me why the `buildAndRun2` method just doesn't compile.

```scala
abstract class BaseFactoryOf[A]{
    type TheType
    def make: TheType
}

abstract class FactoryOf[A] extends BaseFactoryOf[A]{
    final type TheType = A
}

class HelloWorld {
    def execute: String = "Hello World!"
}

class HelloWorldFactory extends FactoryOf[HelloWorld] {
    def make: TheType = new HelloWorld
}

def buildAndRun1[T <: BaseFactoryOf[_],B](factory: T)(f: T#TheType => B): B ={
    f(factory.make)
}

def buildAndRun2[T <: FactoryOf[_],B](factory: T)(f: T#TheType => B): B ={
    f(factory.make)
} //This doesn't compile due to a type mismatch error. But Why?!

//Client Code
buildAndRun1(new HelloWorldFactory)(i => i.execute) // This Works!
buildAndRun2(new HelloWorldFactory)(i => i.execute) // Epic Fail!
```

The useless Intermediate `FactoryOf[A]` was actually written to introduce the issue. I'm pretty sure it's got something to do with the `type TheType` but what is it?! If anything, It's the useless intermediate `FactoryOf` class that allows me to verify that the `type TheType` is the same as `A` so by this logic I should be more confident using `buildAndRun2` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
def buildAndRun3[T <: FactoryOf[_],B](factory: T)(f: factory.TheType => B): B = {
    f(factory.make)
}
```

I suspect that `TheType` is defined in type `FactoryOf` to depend on the argument. That's why the actual type depends on the actual instance given (path-dependent type) and not just the type.

On the other hand, `buildAndRun1` compiles because `TheType` is not defined in the type `BaseFactoryOf` and it should be defined in another type `T` that is a descendant. It could have been defined as something persistent, like `Int`.

Comment: I didn't know I could use the ```factory.TheType``` expression. tnx